# Apply `ListedColormap` on bar chart

Tags: matplotlib

How can I apply a `ListedColormap` (`cmap_cblind = ListedColormap(['#D1BBD7', '#4EB265'])`) on `ax.bar()`?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

cmap_cblind = ListedColormap(['#D1BBD7', '#4EB265'])

species = ('Adelie', 'Chinstrap', 'Gentoo')
sex_counts = {
    'Male': np.array([73, 34, 61]),
    'Female': np.array([73, 34, 58]),
}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bottom = np.zeros(3)

for sex, sex_count in sex_counts.items():
    p = ax.bar(species, sex_count, bottom=bottom)
    bottom += sex_count

plt.show()
```

I tried `ax.bar(species, sex_count, bottom=bottom, color=cmap_cblind)` which returns `TypeError: object of type 'ListedColormap' has no len()`.

Comment: The graph was displayed correctly in my environment (matplotlib:3.6.3). What version are you currently using?

Comment: `matplotlib.__version__` returns `'3.5.3'`.

Comment: You can use `for (sex, sex_count), color in zip(sex_counts.items(), cmap_blind.colors):
    ax.bar(species, sex_count, bottom=bottom, color=color, label=sex)`.  `ax.bar` doesn't work with a colormap, the only valid arguments are a single color, or a list of colors (one for each bar).

Comment: Can I `overwrite` the Matplotlib standard colormap?